# How to get SharedPreference from non activity class for non activity

Tags: java, android, android-context

In my Activity class I store some data in a `Sharedpreference`. My non Activity class has getter and setter to read the `Sharedpreference` data. I want use this Data in an another Activity class. But I get always a Nullpointer exception.

This is a Code snippet from my Activity class.

```
SharedPreferences prefs;

prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(KEY_NAME_FOR_PREF, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("name", name.getText().toString());
editor.commit();
```

This is my first non Activity class

```
private String name;
private Context mContext;

public PdfConsultantContacts(Context context){
    mContext = context;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

And this is my second non Activity class.
    Context mContext; 
    PdfConsultantContacts contact = new PdfConsultantContacts(mContext);

```
void initContact() {
SharedPreferences prefs =        mContext.getApplicationContext().
getSharedPreferences("app_prefs", 0);
contact.setName(prefs.getString("name", null));
}
```

When I try to `contact.getName();` I get always a Nullpointer exception, but I know that the `SharedPreference` are saved correctly.

Comment: default value is null... and how do you know that preference is saved?

Comment: Try  mContext.getSharedPreferences("app_prefs", 0);

Comment: Can you please say where you called initContact()? In activity or non-activity class?

Comment: I know it because i use a textview to display a sharedpreference value. I use it in the non activity class.

Answer (score 2):

Create a class with two static methods and use this throughout your application to store and retrieve data from SharedPreferences.

```
public class Utils {    
            public static void putStringInPreferences(Context context, String value, String key, String pKey) {
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(pKey, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putString(key, value);
                editor.commit();
            }

            public static String getStringFromPreferences(Context context,String defaultValue, String key, String pKey) {
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(pKey, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                String temp = sharedPreferences.getString(key, defaultValue);
                return temp;
            }
    }
```

Comment: I get the same error when i use it like this: testKlasse.getStringFromPreferences(mContext, null , "name", "app_prefs");

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure "Code snippet" from your Activity is really executed, you can verify it by print some log.
2. Make sure the KEY_NAME_FOR_PREF equals "app_prefs".